# On the proof of Additivity over Partitions

Tags: real-analysis

The following text is from the book Advanced Calculus by P. Fitzpatrick:

> **Theorem 18.11** $\ \ $ **Additivity over Partitions** $\ \ $ Let $f:\mathbf I\to\mathbb R$ be a bounded function on the generalized rectangle $\bf I$. Let $\bf P$ be a partition of $\bf I$. Then the function $f:{\bf I}\to{\Bbb R}$ is integrable if and only if for each generalized rectangle $\bf J$ in $\bf P$, the restriction of $f$ to $\bf J$, $f:{\bf J}\to{\Bbb R}$, is integrable: In this case $$\int_{\bf I} f=\sum_{{\bf J}\text{ in }\bf P}\int_{\bf J} f.\tag{18.9}$$
>
> **Proof** 
>   First we suppose that for each generalized rectangle $\bf J$ in $\bf P$, the function $f:{\bf J}\to{\Bbb R}$ is integrable. We will use the Archimedes-Riemann Theorem to show that $f:{\bf I}\to {\Bbb R}$ is integrable. Suppose that there are $m$ generalized rectangles in $\bf P$. Let $k$ be a natural number. Using the Archimedes-Riemann Theorem and criterion (ii) of Theorem 18.10, we see that for each generalized rectangle $\bf J$ in $\bf P$ we can select a partition $\mathbf{P}_k({\bf J})$ of $\bf J$ such that $$U(f,\mathbf{P}_k({\bf J}))-L(f,\mathbf{P}_k({\bf J}))<\frac{1}{km}.$$ Choose $\mathbf{P}_k$ to be a partition of $\bf I$ that contains all the generalized rectangles in any one of the $\mathbf{P}_k({\bf J})$'s. By the distribution formula (18.3) and the Refinement Lemma, $$\begin{align}U(f,\mathbf{P}_k)-L(f,\mathbf{P}_k)&\leq\sum_{{\bf J}\text{ in }\bf P}U(f,\mathbf{P}_k({\bf J}))-L(f,\mathbf{P}_k({\bf J})) \\ < m\frac{1}{km}=\frac{1}{k}.\end{align}$$ Thus, $$\lim_{k\to\infty}[U(f,\mathbf{P}_k)-L(f,\mathbf{P}_k)]=0,$$ and therefore, by the Archimedes-Riemann Theorem, the function $f$ is integrable on $\bf I$.
>
> To prove the converse, suppose that the function $f:{\bf I}\to\mathbb{R}$ is integrable. By the Archimedes-Riemann Theorem we can choose an Archimedean sequence $\{\mathbf{P}_k\}$ of partitions for $f:\mathbf I\to\mathbb R$. Using the Refinement Lemma and possibly replacing each $\mathbf{P}_k$ by a common refinement of $\mathbf{P}_k$ an $\bf P$, we can suppose that each ${\bf P}_k$ is a refinement of $\bf P$. For each natural number $k$, observe that if ${\bf P}_k({\bf J})$ is the partition that ${\bf P}_k$ induces on the generalized rectangle $\bf J$ in $\bf P$, then $$\color{red}{\underline{\color{black}{\displaystyle  U(f,\mathbf{P}_k({\bf J}))-L(f,\mathbf{P}_k({\bf J}))\leq U(f,\mathbf{P}_k)-L(f,\mathbf{P}_k)     }}}.$$ Thus, for each generalized rectangle $\bf J$ in $\bf P$, the sequence of partitions $\{\mathbf{P}_k(\mathbf{J})\}$ is an Archimedean sequence for $f:{\bf J}\to\Bbb R$ and therefore, by the Archimedes-Riemann Theorem, the function $f$ is integrable on $\bf J$.
>
> It remains to verify formula (18.9). However, we have the following distribution formula for the Darboux sums: $$L(f,\mathbf{P}_k)=\sum_{{\bf J}\text{ in }{\bf P}} L(f,\mathb{P}_k({\bf J})).$$ According to the Archimedes-Riemann Theorem, the sequence of lower Darboux sums associated with an Archimedean sequence of partitions converges to the value of the integral. Thus, $$\int_{\bf I}f=\lim_{k\to\infty}L(f,\mathbf{P}_k)=\lim_{k\to\infty}\sum_{{\bf J}\text{ in }\bf P} L(f,\mathbf{P}_k({\bf J}))=\sum_{{\bf J}\text{ in }{\bf P}}\int_{\bf J} f.\tag*{$\blacksquare$}$$

I don't understand the red-underlined inequality. Definitely $U(f, P_k(J)) \le U(f, P_k) = U(f, P_k(I))$ and $L(f, P_k(J)) \le L(f, P_k) = L(f, P_k(I))$ because summation is done on generalized rectangles $J$ and $I$, respectively, and $J \subset I$. However that doesn't result in $U(f, P_k(J)) - L(f, P_k(J)) \le U(f, P_k) - L(f, P_k)$.

A clear simple explanation would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let

$$S_1=U(f, P_k(J))-L(f, P_k(J))=\sum\limits_{S\in P_k(J)} \left(M(f,S)\mathop{vol}(S)-m(f,S)\mathop{vol}(S)\right)$$

and

$$S_2=U(f, P_k)-L(f, P_k)=\sum\limits_{S\in P_k} \left(M(f,S)\mathop{vol}(S)-m(f,S)\mathop{vol}(S)\right)$$

Now $J$ is a generalized rectangle of the partition $P$, and $P_k$ is a refinement of $P$, so $P_k(J)\subseteq P_k$. Therefore the sum $S_2$ runs over all the terms of the $S_1$ and possibly more. The summands are nonnegative, so the inequality $S_2\ge S_1$ holds.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The key point is $U-L \ge 0$ but I forgot!